# React JS Dropdown onchange function does not work. Trying few methods with no success

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, dropdown, onchange

I'm trying to build a dropdown menu using react. But I couldn't get it to get the onchange working.

I tried few methods but still no sucess. Data loads into the dropdown and when I select one, nothing changes.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        serviceList: []
    };
    this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this);
    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
    this.delete = this.delete.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

}

handleChange(e){
    this.setState({[e.target.Name]: e.target.value})
}

fillDropdowncus(list){     
    let result = [];
    for (var key in list) {
        result.push({ key: list[key]['CusId'] , text: list[key]['CusName'] })
    }        
    return result;
}

<Form.Field>
<label>Select customer</label><br />
<Dropdown selection options={this.fillDropdowncus(this.state.customersList)} onChange={this.handleChange} name="selectCustomer" placeholder='Select Customer' /><br />
</Form.Field>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `valueChange` should be `handleChange`.

```
<Dropdown selection options={this.fillDropdowncus(this.state.customersList)} onChange={this.handleChange} name="selectCustomer" placeholder='Select Customer' />
```

Comment: I had created a separate function called valueChange to try a different method. Forgot to rename it when making the post. My bad

Answer (score 0):

Always try to call the functions in an anonymous function first. Try calling onChange={this.handleChange} in your Dropdown class with onChange={() =>this.handleChange}